# Can I specify a regex for the table name on Glue using terraform on Aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I would like to apply the following Terraform [`aws_iam_policy_document` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_policy_document.html):

```
  statement {
    sid= "DeleteTmpTable"
    actions = [
      "glue:DeleteTable",
    ]

    resources = [
    "arn:aws:glue:eu-west-1:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:table/compan-${terraform.workspace}/*_[0-9]+",
    "arn:aws:glue:eu-west-1:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:database/company-${terraform.workspace}",
    "arn:aws:glue:eu-west-1:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:catalog"
    ]
  }
```

So I could only allow Glue Delete Table on tables like `table_name_454044243243` but the tables like `table_name_blablabla` shouldn't be deleteable.

But I can't find any information on the available regex.

Comment: Do you need a regex there or does a wildcard work? Can you show examples of what you don't want to match as well please?

Comment: Yes I updated my question, the table like table_name_blablabla or table_name shouldn't be available to delete.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an AWS IAM restriction rather than a Terraform one. [IAM allows for either multi character wildcards (`*`) or single character wildcards (`?`) but not arbitrary regexes.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_resource.html)

And while [Terraform supports regexes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/regex.html) this doesn't help you because you need to have this create an IAM policy that doesn't.

One option you could do instead is to use Terraform to interpolate the resource that is affected by the IAM policy and so the IAM policy would list all the affected resources literally rather than as a regex or wildcard match.

If you are using Terraform to create the AWS Glue tables then you could do something like this:

```
variable "tables" {
  default = [
    "table_name_454044243243",
    "table_name_454044243244",
    # ...
  ]
}

resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "example" {
  for_each      = toset(tables)
  name          = each.key
  database_name = "MyCatalogDatabase"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example" {
  statement {
    sid= "DeleteTmpTable"

    actions = [
      "glue:DeleteTable",
    ]

    resources = values(aws_glue_catalog_table.example)[*].arn
  }
}
```

If you haven't been using Terraform to create the Glue tables then another option would be to use the [external data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html) to shell out and get the Glue tables with the [AWS CLI which does support matching by regex with the `--expression` parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/get-tables.html) or [Boto 3's `get_tables` method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_tables). An untested example might look something like the following:

```
data "external" "example" {
  program = ["python", "${path.module}/example-get-tables.py"]

  query = {
    database_name = "MyCatalogDatabase"
    expression    = "compan-${terraform.workspace}/*_[0-9]+"
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example" {
  statement {
    sid= "DeleteTmpTable"

    actions = [
      "glue:DeleteTable",
    ]

    resources = data.external.example.tables
  }
}
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import sys

import boto3

glue_client = boto3.client('glue')
query = json.loads(sys.stdin)

response = glue_client.get_tables(
    DatabaseName=query["database_name"],
    Expression=query["expression"]
)

tables = [table["name"] for table in response["TableList"]]
print(json.dumps("tables": tables))
```

Failing all that I would instead strongly recommend that you better namespace your resources so that you can take use of the `*` wildcard matching in your IAM policies if you have control over how the tables are created even if it's just the prefix or a suffix.

Comment: I don't have the name of the tables in advance.

Comment: I've added an untested example of how to get at the tables using an expression. It might not work exactly but it should give you enough of an idea to get it to work. If there's only a small change needed to get it working then feel free to edit the answer to include the changes required to get it working.